# Why is my rspec test failing with ActionController::RoutingError:?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Basically I'm stumped as to why this particular test is failing. The page works fine when I go in and test it out by hand but the test keeps failing. First off, here's the error.

```
 2) Setlist Pages Edit page adding a song 
     Failure/Error: click_button submit
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"setlists", :id=>nil}
     # ./app/controllers/allocations_controller.rb:15:in `create'
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/setlist_pages_spec.rb:79:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I realise that the id is set to nil but I know that when the test initially visits the page it renders because tests for content pass. I'm not sure why it points to the create controller when I'm testing the edit action as well? The test is shown below:

```
before do
   @setlist = Setlist.create(date: Date.today, morning: true)
end
```

...

```
describe "Edit page" do

        let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
        let(:submit){ "Add Song" }

        before do
           @secondSong = FactoryGirl.create(:song)
           sign_in admin
           visit edit_setlist_path(@setlist)
        end

        it{ should have_content("Edit a Setlist")}

        describe "adding a song" do
            before do
                select("#{@secondSong.title} by #{@secondSong.artist}", from: 'Songs')
                click_button submit

            end

            it{ should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success')}

            it "should create a new allocation" do
                expect{click_button submit}.to change(Allocation, :count).by(1)
            end

        end # end adding a song
    end # end edit test
```

Controller code as requested:

```
def create
    @setlist = Setlist.new(params[:setlist])
    if @setlist.save
        #success!
        flash[:success] = "Setlist saved"
      #@setlist.allocations.build produce invalid allocation with nil id
        redirect_to setlist_path(@setlist)
    else
        #FAIL!
        render 'new'
    end
  end
  def edit
    @songs= Song.search(params[:search])
    #@songs = Song.all(order: 'title')
    @setlist = Setlist.find(params[:id])
    @allocations = @setlist.allocations
    @allocation = Allocation.new
    @selections = Song.all.collect {|s| [ [s.title, s.artist].join(" by "), s.id ]}
  end


  def update

    @setlist = Setlist.find(params[:id])
    @selections = Song.all.collect {|s| [ [s.title, s.artist].join(" by "), s.id] }
    @allocations = @setlist.allocations
    @allocation = Allocation.new

    #Allocation parameters
    @allocation.song_id = params[:allocation][:song_id]
    @allocation.setlist_id = @setlist.id
    @allocation.songPosition = @setlist.songs.count + 1

    if @setlist.update_attributes(params[:setlist])
      if @allocation.save
        flash[:success] = "SETLIST SAVED!"
        redirect_to edit_setlist_path(@setlist)
      else
        flash[:fail] = "Sorry there was an error adding songs to the setlist"
        render 'edit'
      end
    else
      flash[:fail] = "Invalid Set"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't `click_button submit` cause the create action to be triggered? You must have something in the create controller action that redirects to `edit` without setting the model.  Some controller code would be helpful here...

Comment: Could you please paste the code for /app/controllers/allocations_controller.rb ?

Comment: Relevant bits of the controller code are up, please let me know if I've posted too much of it

Comment: I couldn't find anything useful but I have this advice for you: in specs when creating object I prefer doing it with the corresponding bang method (create!, save!...). This way, if something goes wrong and the object was not created as expected the test won't keep on running generating errors like these. Try doing it in `@setlist = Setlist.create(date: Date.today, morning: true)` and on other places on the spec, maybe this will reveal the reason for the error.

Comment: It looks like `@setlist.id` is `nil` in your test. What happens when you create with `Setlist.create!` instead of `Setlist.create`?

Comment: Pretty much the exact same thing I'm afraid...

Comment: Does your `Setlist` have a `#to_param` method (this is a long shot). And can you do a `puts @setlist.inspect` just before the exception happens? id should not be nil.

Comment: I don't think so, but I've tried putting a puts @setlist.id before the `select("#{@secondSong.title} by #{@secondSong.artist}", from: 'Songs')` line and it says that the setlist id at this point is 1.

Comment: I'm not sure just from what's here, but this looks like it might possibly be related to how capybara deals with session cookies. I'd try playing around a bit with the sign_in step.